# Improper Integrals and convergence of the limit of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that if $f$ is a non-negative valued continuous function with domain $[1,\infty)$ such that $lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)dx$ exists then the improper integral $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$ converges and $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$=$lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{1}^n f(x)dx$

I know that for the improper integral to converge would imply that the sequence is bounded and this would also mean that the corresponding sequence of partial sums would need to be bounded. I am unsure of where to go at this point or how to answer this problem.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$?

Comment: What is your definition of "improper integral converging"?

Comment: I know it is used for the integral test ie. if  $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$ converges than so will the infinite series and if it diverges than so will the series for a continuous non negative and non increasing function on the half line.

Comment: I think the question is whether it is a Riemann or Lebesgue integral ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is both non-negative and continuous and that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} I_n =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^n f(t) \, dt = L.$$

Then, as $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^{\lfloor x \rfloor} f(t) \, dt = L.$$

Note that

$$0 \leqslant \int_1^x f(t) \,dt - \int_1^{\lfloor x\rfloor } f(t) \,dt = \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor }^x f(t) \,dt \leqslant \int_{\lfloor x\rfloor }^{\lfloor x\rfloor+1} f(t) \,dt.$$

We have by the Cauchy criterion, $|I_{n+1} - I_n| < \epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large since the sequence $(I_n)$ is convergent. Hence, the limit of the integral on the RHS must be zero as $x \to \infty$.

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x f(t) \,dt = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^{\lfloor x\rfloor } f(t) \,dt = L.$$

Comment: what is the use for the absolute values around x in this context?

Comment: @sappgob: not needed as $f$ is positive -- will edit