# Improper integrals in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Prove that, if $f$ is a non-negative continuous function with domain $[1,\infty$) such that the limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx$$ (where $n$ is an integer) exists, then the improper integral

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

converges and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx = \int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$$

---

I honestly have no idea where to even start with this proof, because to me this looks like the definition of an improper integral.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The issue is the difference between the limit-along-the-integers $\lim_n\int_1^n f(x)\,dx$ and the "continuous limit" $\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_1^b f(x)\,dx$. Referring to the definitions of these two limits, it's not hard to see that the existence of the latter implies that of the former. Your task is to show that the existence of the former implies that of the latter (and that the two limits coincide).

Comment: What about the Dirichlet integral $\int_0^\infty x^{-1}\sin x\,dx$?

Comment: @plshelp is asking about a *non-negative* integrand.

Comment: Asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1680540/148510

Answer (score 2):

You're overlooking an important thing.
The initial assumption is the existence of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx$, where the limit is taken over integer points $n$ (consider this as the usual limit of a sequence).

You cannot foresee a priori the behaviour of $\int_1^t f(x) \,dx$ when $t$ is not an integer.

That's when the non-negativity of $f$ comes into play: it tells you that the function $t\to \int_1^t f(x) \,dx$  is increasing, and it therefore has a limit as $t$ goes to $\infty$, say $L\in [0,\infty]$.

But it's possible to prove formally (using the very definition of limits) that  $$\lim_{n\to\infty, n\in \mathbb N}\int_{1}^{n}f(x)\,dx =\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_1^t f(x) \, dx= L $$

Hence $L$ is finite.